# Adding opencontrail to maas juju openstack

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have a working icehouse openstack environment with neutron ovs and gre tunnels.
The environment was set using maas and juju (deployed openstack charms).

Would like to configure opencontrail instead of ovs in neutron and I am looking for assistance here.

The environment is juju controlled hence manually editing the config files e.g. neutron.conf is not a choice.

I see opencontrail related chrams in juju charm store, but there ins't much details including what relations it may require.

Thanks,
Astar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenContrail Juju charms are under development here:

- https://jujucharms.com/q/contrail/robert-ayres

With a Juju Deployer config here:

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robert-ayres/+junk/contrail-deployer/view/head:/juju-deployer/contrail.yaml

These charms can be used to deploy OpenContrail today.

Although speaking as the author of these charms, they need a little work before they're ready for general public use. For example, Simple Gateway support (required for launched VMs to access the outside world) isn't in yet. However, they can be used as guidance for setting up OpenContrail manually.

Comment: I see following charms contrail-control | contrail-configuration | neutron-contrail. Can I deploy these on single machine? Also, can you please let me know what relations should be created for these charms e.g. juju add-relation ceilometer mongodb
juju add-relation ceilometer rabbitmq-server

Comment: Yes, they can be deployed on a single machine using the local provider. http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robert-ayres/+junk/contrail-deployer/view/head:/README provides instructions for doing this.

Comment: The relations required are in the Juju Deployer contrail.yaml file linked, under the 'relations:' sections.

Comment: I'll give a try will all information provided by you.